# pilz industrial motion planner not using the updated allowed collision matrix

Tags: moveit, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**My environment:**

- ROS Noetic in a docker container with Ubuntu 20.04
- Moveit! version 1.1.2
- ros-industrial-client with motoman driver

**Problem:**

- Using MoveGroup commander (Python API) and Pilz Industrial Motion Planner, changes to the allowed collision matrix (ACM) are published to the planning scene but do not propagate to the planning interface.

**Action taken so far:**

- Tested with an identical stack except with OMPL planner in the pipeline. Behaviour is not reproducible, changes propagate to the planning interface (perhaps through pre/post-processing plugins?).
- Tested with planning directly in rviz. Behaviour is not reproducible, changes propagate to the planning interface.

**Question:**

- Why does OMPL planner with MoveGroup Commander or planning directly in rviz with Pilz Industrial Motion Planner successfully use the updated planning scene yet the Pilz Industrial Motion Planner with MoveGroup Commander does not?
- Is there an API call to force the MoveGroup Commander to fetch an updated planning scene?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378602/pilz-industrial-motion-planner-not-using-the-updated-allowed-collision-matrix/) by [robertjbush](https://answers.ros.org/users/73762/robertjbush/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-19**:
Which part specifically is the "ros-industrial stack"?

The Pilz planner is a MoveIt planner written by Pilz. MoveIt  is MoveIt.

There doesn't appear to be anything *ros-industrial* here.

**Comment by [robertjbush](https://answers.ros.org/users/73762/robertjbush/) on 2021-05-19**:
Question guidelines: *"Names and versions of stacks/packages that you're using"*. If there should be boundaries to what the op includes in their question, then the guidelines need to be made clearer. I use ros-industrial-client and motoman stacks. I also consider pilz to be most relevant for industrial users.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-05-19**:
I have been using the pilz planner while modifying the ACM, but have not encountered this bug. If you can reproduce it with a minimal example, please feel free post it on the Github issue tracker.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-20**:\

> I use ros-industrial-client and motoman stacks.

that isn't mentioned anywhere in your question text. "ros-industrial stack" is not a well known bit of terminology. No one will know what you mean by that, so it does not add anything which would help understand your setup.

**Comment by [robertjbush](https://answers.ros.org/users/73762/robertjbush/) on 2021-05-20**:
@fvd do you have a github repo where I could view working moveit config files and python scripts? Moved to github issue [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2676).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue has been fixed and merged into the master branch of MoveIt!. See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2676) for more info.

---

Originally posted by [robertjbush](https://answers.ros.org/users/73762/robertjbush/) with karma: 31 on 2021-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0